# Remove a div with an empty ul tag in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I have to remove a div with an empty ul tag in it.

**EDIT**: The ul tag is not empty, it has a bunch of whitespace in it.

I want to do this with jQuery

This is what I have so far:

```
$('trim(#menu):empty').parent().remove();
```

Where the id of my div is 'menu'.

**Example:**

before:

```
<div id="container>
    <div id="menu">
      <ul>          


      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

after:

```
<div id="container>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Stijn

Comment: Since when has "trim()" been a selector?

Comment: `:empty` won't select a node that contains whitespace, because that's considered a text node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get the idea but this could do the trick

```
if ($('#menu li').length == 0) {
   $('#menu').remove();
}
```

Comment: I've edited my question. The ul is not empty, it contains whitspace.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
if($("#menu ul:not:has(li)")) {
    $("#menu").parent().remove();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Although it seems right...

Do I have to add document.onload or something? I'm really a beginner when it comes to JavaScript.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need: `$(document).ready(function() { //code here });`

Comment: check my edited post.. That's the BEST way but if it doesn't work try out my first revision.

Comment: Very nice. It seems so logic. But I can't get it to work :/.

http://jsfiddle.net/yxkHM/

Comment: @Mohammed Areeb Siddiqui: Thanks for your effort, but Claudio Redi fixed it another way around.

Comment: Atleast you can give it a +1.. can't you?